# CSS3 Transitions + jQuery : translations of the x-axis have different results in different browsers for two different items

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/nickgofly/pen/DHFbv): (Here's a codepen for those who want to jump straight in. Try it in Chrome and IE to see the difference in results)

I'm attempting to use css3 transformations/transitions because, well, they're much more fluid than the jquery effects.

I have a mobile version of a site that has a fixed bar at the top with the logo on it and a navicon. When the navicon is clicked or touched, a side navigation bar pops out from the left.

This is where css3 comes in. I had a working version of this functionality with jQuery alone, but the animation was really choppy on phones. I downloaded the jQuery transit plug-in, which basically integrates css3 transitions into jQuery as if they were animations (but this is beside the point - I don't think the problem lies here).

With the css3 version, when I move my content body and my fixed header with x: [some amount], the transformation shows differently for different browsers. In every desktop browser with the exception of IE10, the fixed header flies out double what it should, while the content body shifts to the right the right amount. In my phone, in chrome, the header flies out double what it should while not doing so in the default Android browser.

More info: I checked with chrome inspector, and both the header and the content body are receiving the same transformation ([some number]px, 0). THE HEADER IS NESTED WITHIN THE CONTENT BODY. I think that's where the problem lies. Some browsers move the header with the content, and then interpret the transformation of the header again. On the other hand, since the position is fixed, some browsers interpret the two transformations independently.

My question: What technicalities cause this discrepancy and what can be done to get consistent results across all modern browsers?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/nickgofly/pen/DHFbv): (Like I said, on Chrome it doesn't work as expected but if you try IE it does)

Comment: It helps if you post a link to a Fiddle and some code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry I was in the midst of creating a test file. I appended it at the end of my post ^^. Load the codepen in IE and Chrome to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind it is navbar being child of the `#bod` element, when `#bod` moves navbar also moves with it. You also applied another transition to navbar which repositions it for the second time. Different treatment by browsers is caused by using the transition with the 'fixed' property value. A simpler and more applicable solution is to use toggleClass() method on `#bod` and achieve what you want with less code. Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/tuncelmert/pen/oZVvGo).
Css addition:

```
#bod {
    transition: margin .5s ease-in-out;
}
#bod.menu-open {
    margin-left: 30%;
}
```

and the simpler js:

```
$("#toggle").on("touchstart mousedown", function (event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#bod').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```